# BCMWL WiFi not working for me. Can I get a reminder on how to get it working in Odin?

Tags: wifi, elementary-project, release-odin

I just installed Odin on an older Windows 8 vintage Dell laptop.  I have totally forgotten how to troubleshoot the chipset and get the kernel sources installed correctly.   I’ve gotten as far as installing the BCMWL Kernel source package from AppCenter, but I am totally lost.

Comment: This is solved.  I don’t recall how to close it other than this comment, so sorry if it falls outside the usual expectations for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have been struggling with this, too. You need to install Kernel Headers first. See this:

https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/526#issue-965454894

you might need to
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment: use the checkmark left to my answer, below the down/upvote arrows to mark it as solved