# Unable to turn on Wifi adaptor after updating to Odin

Tags: wifi, drivers, lenovo, release-odin

I installed the new elementary OS on my Lenovo laptop. Network settings only shows wired network.

Comment: Please go to System Settings > System > Firmware and check if there's any driver available for your wifi card.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out what your wireless adapter is and then get those drivers installed. There are some good guides around for Broadcom e.g., https://www.thetestspecimen.com/posts/broadcom-bluetooth-fedora/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps as well, at least for me standard procedure without installing  Kernel headers first did not work: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/28315/26554